# Swift4 Side Menu Shows Black Status Bar

Tags: ios, swift4

I am trying to use this library https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu for Side Menu in swift4. In new version some syntax was deprecated.The Status bar in Side Menu is showing Black         `SideMenuManager.default.menuFadeStatusBar = false`

This was working fine earlier but now it is giving a warning `'menuFadeStatusBar' is deprecated: This property has been moved to the SideMenuNavigationController class.`
Image for the same is attached below.

[image]

how can I remove black Status Bar when sidemenu appears?

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: how can I remove Black Status Bar when sidemenu appears? @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is solution:

```
let leftMenuNavigationController = SideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: YourViewController)
SideMenuManager.default.leftMenuNavigationController = leftMenuNavigationController
```

Prevent status bar area from turning black when menu appears:

```
leftMenuNavigationController.statusBarEndAlpha = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have set the value for StatusBarEndAlpha to 0 under Attributes Inspector in storyboard. I made only this change and the black view on top has disappeared:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Swift4 :- I got another stuff.
On side Menu Button Action call SideMenu class manually

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        if let theController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SideMenuNavigationController") as? SideMenuNavigationController {
            SideMenuPresentationStyle.menuSlideIn.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            theController.presentationStyle = .menuSlideIn
            theController.presentationStyle.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            navigationController?.present(theController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```